# how to customize form.mini.phtml in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to make some changes in `form.mini.phtml`

I found it here:

> vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml

Where in my theme do I need to place that file to make changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to put path like this

```
app/design/frontend/yourspacename/yourtheme/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your current theme create the same folder structure and copy the file then do the modification there.